# Show warning message before close window in Java Script

Tags: javascript

I've try this:

```
<body onunload="LogoutNoAsk();"> </body>
```

and the function is:

```
function LogoutNoAsk()
{
    alert("Please press the Logout button to logout.");
    parent.close();

}
```

When I press close which is the 'X' button on the top right of the window, it close straightaway without the warning message. What's wrong?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You're actually wanting to use the `onbeforeunload` event which allows you to block the close event.

See the [MDN reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.onbeforeunload) for details, but the code required would be:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function(e) {
    return 'Please press the Logout button to logout.';
};
```

Comment: You mean I have to put this line : window.onbeforeunload = function(e) {return 'Please press the Logout button to logout.';};, into my LogoutNoAsk() function?

Comment: I've try it, it still give user to choose between 'Stay on the page' or 'Leave the page'. Can we not asking the user to choose? I just want the warning message with a OK button.

Comment: Nope, you can't control the options of the dialog, that's something the browser controls. As for the location you can either change the `LogoutNoAsk` to return that and change the `DOM` to have a `onbeforeunload` attribute not `onunload` or you can use JS to wire up the event handler.