# Wait until a callback address is called

Tags: javascript, php

I am programming an educational web in PHP and JS and I interact with another webpage that corrects for me some programming exercises. 
I don't know when this correction will finish, but this correction webpage calls a given address when the correction is available.
Is it possible to wait for that result with PHP or JS and then do some stuff (not just showing the result to the user), even if the user closes the tab?

Thanks in advance.

STEP BY STEP explanation:

1. A student is trying to do a programming exercise. The statement of the exercise is shown, as well as other details to complete it.
2. When he thinks he has reached a solution, he uploads his code. Then, he can wait (or not) for the correction to finish.

   1. My web page uploads then the code file (with other files as well as an address to callback when it finishes) to the corrector webpage.
   2. I keep waiting until the callback is made.
3. When the correction is finished, I do some stuff like assigning a grade to the student and, if he/she stayed on the same page, he/she can see details of the correction.

The correction is done by another webpage and I don't know when it would finish, but when it finishes it calls a given adress (for example: www.example.com/ex1sub1usr1 ).

The doubts are between step 2 and 3. It is possible to do all this process with PHP/JS? If not, what are the alternatives?

Comment: Do you mean you want push notifications when the correction has finished?
Something like: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/eventsource/basics/

Comment: Nope. It is not necessary to notify the user immediately. He can close everything but when the correction finishes, the grade for that student in that exercise must be updated.

Comment: I assume the grade is stored in a DB? You will need the server-sent events if you want to notify a user when his grade changed. If the user is not online, just leave the grade in the db and set a flag called `notified` to false. So you know when he logs in again, he didn't see his grade last time. I think another approach might be the correct decision here...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Updated Answer

- Create a PHP script on your server which updates your grade database when visited with a specially formulated URL, eg. `http://yourserver.com/update.php?user=2429&sub=1&ex=1`

  - specify this as the target URL when you submit for correction
  - *if you are restricted to your `/ex1sub1usr1` format then just use regex to parse the URL*
- When user refreshes (or returns to your site) the data should be appropriately pulled from your PHP backend

For bonus points, you could have your submission screen (or the entire website) intermittently poll another PHP script URL on your server (with [XHR](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest)) for an "updated" flag, and live update the page.

### Considerations

Your only major concern will then be ensuring that the form data (ie. their code) is submitted completely.  Consider using [XHR](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest) to submit your form data and temporarily enabling a [window closure warning](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15514703/679950) until upload is complete.

---

## Original "Answer"

Since there isn't much information to go by here, I will have to make a few assumptions:

- you presumably can't reliably spawn a process to watch the associated results address
- you don't need to notify the user immediately (push notifications), but they need eventually see their result, eg. when they return to your page
- results stay around for a while
- as you mention, this must work even if the user closes the tab

Given this scenario, I would merely check the results page when the user returns to your site.

Just store the results address in session vars - either via PHP or a cookie - then when the user returns you can perform any unfinished checks and update accordingly.

*NB: Should further information surface in the question I will gladly provide further details*

Comment: I have edited the topic trying to make a cleaner explanation. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can perform all necessary actions on a script behind the given address that is called by the remote website after the excersises have been corrected.

It is absolutely not possible to show/do anything on client side if the user has closed the tab.

Comment: But I want the given callback adress to be unique, as there can be lots of corrections in the same time. How can I assign a script with some parameters like studentid, exercise..behind every given address?

Comment: You could use an address like `http://www.example.com/callback.php?ex=exercise1&u=user1` and as many parameters as you need. The file `callback.php` reads the parameters (e.g. `$user = $_GET["u"];` and can use them for further processing.