# show fancybox popup before close browser window

Tags: javascript, popup, fancybox

When user close the browser window I want to show fancybox  popup with confirm custom message, or my div with my style and image. How I can do it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Show warning message before close window in Java Script](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15514674/show-warning-message-before-close-window-in-java-script)

Answer (score 0):

With Jquery, you have to bind the **beforeunload** event to a function.

Try this :

```
$(window).bind('beforeunload', function () {
    // display fancybox popup
});
```